# Detect if <audio> `pause` event fired by user interaction or buffer underrun?

Tags: javascript, audio, html5-audio, mediaelement, mediasession

When playing a live audio stream, like web radio, through [`<audio>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/audio) or [`Audio()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLAudioElement/Audio), the pause event can fire in (at least) three ways:

1. user clicks on the pause button (with `<audio controls>`)
2. user clicks the browsers global audio controls

   - iOS: [Control Center](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control_Center_(iOS))
   - Android: browser's notification drawer (at least Chrome, Opera, Firefox)
   - Desktop: [Media Session API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Media_Session_API) controls, but uninitialized, without explicit `setActionHandler` (might be hidden behind a flag as of now)
3. a buffer underrun caused by various network conditions

**Is it possible to distinguish between 1/2 and 3?**

- Ideally, there would be an event property like [`isTrusted`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/isTrusted), which I am missing
- I have tried to guess, looking esp. at [`readyState`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/readyState) and [`networkState`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/networkState), but both are very inconclusive, especially across browsers (e.g. the interpretation/semantics of `HAVE_FUTURE_DATA` vs `HAVE_ENOUGH_DATA`)
- I have shied away from making a "decaying state machine", juggling other events. A buffer underrun is *often* preceded by `stalled` events, and *sometimes* followed by `ended` events. A cross-browser implementation seems crazy complex and the danger of false positives very high.

Am I out of luck until Media Session [lands](https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5639924124483584) everywhere?

Note: [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30297561/how-to-distinguish-between-two-onpause-events-caused-by-clicking-pause-but) looks like a solution, but unfortunately isn't -- browsers handle live streams' "ends" differently and inconsistently.

Answer (score 0):

The [`waiting`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/waiting_event) event should fit your needs.

You can try this demo while you simulate bad network with the dropdown in Chrome's Network tab (e.g: Slow 3G)

```js
const video = document.getElementById('mwe_player_0');
video.onwaiting = function() { console.log('onwaiting'); };
```

```html
<video id="mwe_player_0" controls="" preload="none" style="width:800px;height:450px"><source src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/2/22/Volcano_Lava_Sample.webm" type="video/webm; codecs=&quot;vp8, vorbis&quot;"></video>
```

Note that this demo works with `HTMLAudioElement` as well (because it inherits `HTMLMediaElement`). The video demo is just easier to test.

Comment: Thanks, but again, I'd have to set some flag, like `was_waiting`, to then reason that the `pause` was *maybe* a network event (how much time has to pass so it isn't?). If it wasn't clear enough: I have to deal with the `pause`, not find an alternative. I've had some success in my narrower use case with the similar `ended` event: for a live stream that is expected to be playing (again, a flag), a `pause` event that precedes `ended`, becomes moot - and I can deduce, that any other `pause` *must* be user interaction... until a new control scheme comes along ;)

Comment: ...tl;dr: I had looked at this & other events, still frustratingly implicit guess-work, at best.

Comment: Why do you have to deal with the `pause` event while it doesn't fire on lack of data?

Comment: `pause` events *do* happen for finite resources, they become moot for **live streams only**

Answer (score 0):

If you want to start an event when the user pauses the audio then this snippet will do the job. I didn't test it on mobile in the notification drawer but I think it'll work.

```
const video = document.querySelector('video');

video.addEventListener('pause', (event) => {
  console.log('The Boolean paused property is now true. Either the ' + 
  'pause() method was called or the autoplay attribute was toggled.');
});
```

[resource](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/audio): audio element events

[resource](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/pause_event): pause event

I also found a helpful answer to what you are trying to do **2** (at least from what I understand) and why it's a bad technique. [Link to question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3514784/what-is-the-best-way-to-detect-a-mobile-device)

**3** Events: stalled / waiting check the events resource

Comment: Nope, sorry. This just listens for the event, but does not discern its origin.
Also, I am not trying to do any UA/mobile-sniffing in the classic sense.