# Web audio / radio streaming client: use Howler.js, native Audio, other library?

Tags: javascript, audio, html5-audio, audio-streaming, howler.js

I have been building a web radio player for live streams & static files (MP3 over http). I picked [Howler.js](https://howlerjs.com/) as the back-end to normalize the [quirks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60182909/detect-if-audio-pause-event-fired-by-user-interaction-or-buffer-underrun) of [HTML5 Audio](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLAudioElement/Audio) (think: Autoplay, fading in/out, progress events).
Unfortunately, I ran into several bugs (e.g. [incompatibility with iOS Control Center](https://github.com/goldfire/howler.js/issues/1383), [event handling](https://github.com/goldfire/howler.js/issues/1262)) and found some "creative" workarounds -- but, right now, I'm at the point where I have serious doubts that the cost to use Howler overweighs the benefits. Furthermore:

- streaming MP3s with HTML5 Audio sometimes seems like an afterthought - the API does not really reliably tell you what's going on (buffer underruns, network errors). Or it [glitches](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1592601).
- Howler seems more focused on the Web Audio API (think: games, sound fx) than on its HTML5 part, even if the first two demos on the home page ("Music Player", "Live Radio") suggest otherwise.

So now, before I ditch Howler and just go with the browser's native Audio API, and hopefully don't run into unforeseen problems: **has someone been at this point and can advise?

Are there other libraries I have overlooked?**

I realize this is a rather soft question, unfortunately -- any suggestions on where to ask or what other information to provide are greatly appreciated.

Comment: did you try jPlayer [link](http://jplayer.org/)    (HTML5 Audio & Video for jQuery)

Comment: @AashifAhamed - sounds good, I'll check it out & report back, thx!

Comment: see comment to @AashifAhamed's answer below for analysis of jPlayer. (Doesn't cut it.)

Answer (score 0):

Howler is the most popular audio library on NPM with more than 12k weekly downloads. here is some other popular libraries.

[ReactPlayer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-player)

[wavesurfer.js](https://wavesurfer-js.org/)

[jPlayer](http://jplayer.org/)

[Sound.js](https://createjs.com/soundjs)

[SoundManager 2](https://www.npmjs.com/package/soundmanager2)

Comment: I finally got around to test these. **wavesurfer**: only Web Audio, doesn't play streams. **Sound.js**: doesn't play streams. **ReactPlayer**: seems focused mainly on React, weird API. iOS ControlCenter breaks it. Unaware of Firefox Bug. Online demos broken. **SoundManager 2**: we already had replaced it b/c of weird incompatibilities & unmaintainedness. **jPlayer**: seems focused on UI, depends on jQuery. Looks *ancient* ("Firebug"). Can stream & the only one which would interoperate with iOS ControlCenter. Lots of open issues, re: unmaintedness, mediaSession, iOS bugs. Sigh.

Comment: tl;dr: no solution.